# Start activity from a AdapterRecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, start-activity

I have a `viewPager` with some fragments (in a fragment I have a `recyclerView` ), `recyclerView` contains more items, so, I want to when I click a item on `recyclerView`,it trans to `BBBBActivity`. But I don't figure out.

[image]

it errors
thank you very much

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *context* to call `startActivity()`. Pass `getActivity()` as a context from your Fragment where you are initializing your adapter; like:

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity, /* other parameters*/);
```

In adapter:

```
private Context mContext;

YourAdapter(Context context, /*other parameters*/) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

And then use mContext to call startActivity():

```
mContext.startActivity();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Intent intent= new Intent(itemView.getContext(),addsongList.class);
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Danh happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this or pass the `Context` in your `adapter`

```
Intent intent= new Intent(itemView.getContext(),AddSongToList.class);
getActivity.startActivity(intent);
```